# V has a linearly independent subset S = {s1, ... , sk} & basis β = {b1, ... ,bn}. Why is {s1, ... , sk, b1, ... , bn} a spanning set of V?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for the linearly independent subset S, for λ1s1 + λ2s2 + .. + λksk = 0, the coefficients λ1 = λ2 = .. = λk = 0. I also know that for the basis β, the vectors b1, .. , bn are linearly independent and also span(β) = V. However, I do not know how to link both ideas that I know to conclude that the set {s1, .. ,sk, b1, .. ,bn} is a spanning set for V. Thanks!

Comment: Since $\beta$ spans $V$, any $v \in V$ can be written as $v = a_1b_1 + \cdots + a_nb_n + 0s_1 + \cdots + 0s_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\beta$ is a basis, $\operatorname{span}(\beta)=V$. So, since $S\cup\beta\supset\beta$, $\operatorname{span}(S\cup\beta)=V$.

Answer (score 0):

A spanning set remains a spanning set when further vectors are added.